# Error al crear una tabla con gt en R

Tags: r, dataframe, table, tibble

Estoy intentando crear una tabla utilizando el paquete `gt` en R, pero me genera un error que no logro resolver. Aquí está el código que estoy utilizando:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"),
  Score = c(85, 92, 78, 90, 88)
)

library(gt)

df_gt <- gt(df)
df_gt
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

```
Error in vctrs::vec_chop(do.call(render_row_data, body_rows_data_flat),  : 
  unused argument (sizes = ns)
```

He buscado en la documentación del paquete `gt` y he revisado mi código varias veces, pero no logro identificar cuál es el problema. Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera orientarme sobre cómo solucionar este error y crear la tabla correctamente utilizando `gt`.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Acabo de reproducir tu ejemplo y funciona perfectamente, estas trabajando con los mismos datos que pusiste en tu pregunta?

Comment: Trabajo con otros datos, pero incluso al poner los del ejemplo me genera el mismo error. Este es el show traceback: 6.
create_body_component_h(data = data)
5.
render_as_html(data = x)
4.
htmltools::HTML(render_as_html(data = x))
3.
as.tags.gt_tbl(x, ...)
2.
print.gt_tbl(x)
1.
(function (x, ...)
UseMethod("print"))(x)

Comment: Sugerencias: 1) vuelve a instalar `gt` 2) Prueba tu mismo ejemplo desde una sesión "limpia"